# Segue from A to C by including B

Tags: ios

Is it possible to segue from `A` to `C` but including `B` in the navigation stack? So if I were to dismiss `C` I'd get back to `B`?

I've looked around and didn't find anything that explains this.. I tried solving it with `NSNotificationCenter` but didn't work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy

A `[self.navigationController pushViewController:B animated:NO];`

B `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mYEKCollectionViewController animated:YES];
}`

Comment: mYEKCollectionViewController is C ,by the way  U can use flag to contrl B view appear code in B viewWillAppear.

Comment: Yeah, this works.. But is there a smoother way to do this? Seems rather "hacky"

Comment: A:`[self.navigationController addChildViewController:B];`

Comment: A:`[self.navigationController pushViewController:C animated:YES];`  try

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can edit the content in the uinavigationcontroller's viewControllers.

Info here:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621873-viewcontrollers?language=objc

You will need the notifications or another mechanism to find the correct time to edit the list. But if the view controller is listed in the viewcontrollers stack you won't navigate back to it.

Comment: You segue from A to C. When C is about to be shown, you insert B into the list of viewControllers. You should likely use viewWillAppear, but there are likely other notifications that would tell you about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing the C to the navigation stack, append B so that when you pop the last viewController in C, you get back to B

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.append(B)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(C, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for maintain your navigation sequence ...A -> B -> C

```
1. go to ViewController C 

    ViewControllerc *objvcC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objvcC animated:YES];



2. then add ViewController to existing navigation stack


   ViewControllerB *objViewControllerB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"];
   NSMutableArray *existNavigationArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
   [existNavigationArray insertObject:objViewControllerB atIndex:existNavigationArray.count -1];
   self.navigationController.viewControllers = existNavigationArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Append B first and call push for C

   ```
   self.navigationController?.viewControllers.append(B)
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(C, animated: false)
   ```
2. call push C and append to second last for B

   ```
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(C, animated: false)
   self.navigationController?.viewControllers.insert(B, at: self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count - 1)
   ```

Do what is feasible for you.

And you can also do that like
call pushViewController for C at viewWillAppear of B